# jquery keyup event on text box get id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have build a form in html where dynamically generate some input field with dynamic ids(e.g `id_1`, `id_2`, `id_3` etc). Now I want to create a event when I `keyup` on each input box.

here is my html file

```
<div id="addinput">
    <div id="innneraddinput">
        <div class="inputDivId">
            <input class="search" id="searchid" type="text" size="30" name="p_new" value="" placeholder="" />
        </div>
        <div class="inputDivId">
            <input type="text" id="p_new" size="10" name="p_new" value="" placeholder="" />
        </div>
        <div class="inputDivId">
            <input type="text" id="p_new" size="10" name="p_new" value="" placeholder="" />
        </div>
        <div class="inputDivId">
            <input type="text" id="p_new" size="10" name="p_new" value="" placeholder="" />
        </div>
        <div class="inputDivId">
            <input type="text" id="p_new" size="10" name="p_new" value="" placeholder="" />
        </div>
        <div class="inputDivId">
            <input type="text" id="p_new" size="15" name="p_new" value="" placeholder="" />
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="addNew">Add</a>

    </div>
<div id="result"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how to get id of each input field when I keyup on there.

Comment: What are you doing that you need to find the `id` (again and again and again...) on every key stroke?

Comment: Actually its needs for search some result from database for each fields. When I keyup & press key its also will be shows list of result.

Comment: @Supravat Update your answer by adding a question or describing your problem. That's essential for a question on StackOverflow and shouldn't be hidden in the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#innneraddinput input").keyup(function() {
        var v = this.id;
});
```

If elements are created dynamically, use the `on` method:

```
$("#innneraddinput input").on("keyup", function() {
        var v = this.id;
});
```

Comment: Please don't, just use `this.id`; it's JavaScript: don't over complicate it unnecessarily.

Comment: Well, the question itself is kind of strange. So I guess the author is going to do some jQuery work with the `id` once it's read.

Comment: And? It's going to be the same string whether you use the DOM property or (needlessly) expensive jQuery methods to retrieve the `id`.

Comment: Kristoffer, this is working but when I dynamically create another innneraddinput div and add field into innneraddinput div this is not working. Please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Supravat: dont forget to set the answer as accepted, if you think it is.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#innneraddinput input").keyup(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
}
```